# Using Chebychev's Inequality to Obtain a Lower Bound Given P(-1.5<x<3.5)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be continuous with pdf $f(x)=e^{-x}$ if $0<x<\infty$, and $0$ otherwise. How can I use Chebychev's Inequality to find a lower bound? I have very few examples work from, and I do understand that I could find the exact probability with the information given but the idea is to use Chebychev.

According to my calculations $\mu=1$ and $\sigma^2=2$. With this in mind I set up the inequality to read:

$$P(|x-1|<2.5)\geq 1-\dfrac{1}{(\dfrac{2.5}{\sqrt2})^2}$$

Which would yield:

$$P(|x-1|<2.5) \geq0.68$$

I have absolutely no examples to work from dealing with Chebychev specifically, and I believe the actual probability is about $0.97$. Is there anyway to provide guidance as to whether my process was correct or not?

Comment: Check your calculation of the variance. The process was correct though.

Comment: I think caught where I went wrong. Variance should be 1. The inequality should be greater than 0.84 I believe.

Comment: @user3753 That´s true.